# BSS138 mosfet not for level shifting

Tags: transistors, constant-current, mosfet-driver

i want to build a constant current source to drive an LED like the one in the image below. I want to use a BSS138 N-mosfet transistor which is mainly used in logic level shifting. My question is if i can use a transistor like this or is it used only for level shifting? Will this be able to dim the led according to the potentiometer voltage? In simulation it worked just great but i wanted to get a second opinion.

Thank you[image]

Comment: It will work as long as you have enough volts available from the op amp.

Comment: Just because some hobby site based a logic level shifter around the BSS138 doesn't mean that's its primary use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will work fine. The BSS138 needs about 2.5V Vgs to be sure of reaching 20mA. I get that from the Vgs(th) voltage of 1.5V maximum (1.3V typical) to get 1mA. You need 20mA (1V across 50 ohms) so refer to [Figure 5](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/BS/BSS138.pdf) and adjust for possible unit to unit variations and add some safety factor.  The resistor needs 1V, so that's 3.5V.

The LMV342 output, even with a 10K load to 2.5V, will swing to within 40mV of the +5 supply over the entire temperature range, so you have almost 1.5V to spare.

The other worry is that the capacitive load may cause the op-amp to oscillate. In this case the capacitive load appears like around 40pF (maybe a bit more because of small Miller effect due to changes in the LED Vf with current) with 50 ohms series with some of it. [Figure 30](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmv341-n.pdf) indicates the op-amp with virtually no resistive load can handle 100pF without going unstable, so you're okay, but not a lot of margin.

[image]

By the way, your premise that the BSS138 is primarily used for level shifting is not correct. It's a general purpose small logic level MOSFET, used in a great many applications. Here are the data sheet suggestions:

[image]

Your application does fall outside of that range of applications because the MOSFET is used in a linear mode rather than switching.

Comment: How did you find the 40pf value for the capacitive load from figure 30? Thanks

Comment: I added the G-S capacitance 27pF to the G-D capacitance 13pF, since they're both 'almost' AC grounded on the other side (the G-D capacitance less so, hence my Miller comment- but even if it doubles the effective capacitance you're still well under 100pF).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the BSS138 N Channel MOSFET in the shown circuit in place of the NPN transistor.

There are some limitations to consider when trying to do this however. For some N-Fets the gate drive voltage needed to achieve the desired current flow may be higher than the op-amp circuit can provide. This could be due to FETs that have a particularly high threshold voltage. It can also be due to cheap op-amps like the LM324 that cannot swing their output all the way to the Vcc rail. And lastly the the supply to the op-amp may be too low to achieve the needed gate drive voltage.